# Oracle apex - Interactive Grid setSelectedRecords does not work

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to set selected records in apex Interactive Grid following documentation
[API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html#setSelectedRecords) but it does not work.

I have an array of records and when I am trying to set selected records using

```
apex.region("grid").widget().interactiveGrid("setSelectedRecords", records);
```

or

```
grid.setSelectedRecords(records);
```

when I check it via console the output is like below but the rows are not selected (selection is empty as I would pass the empty array.

[console output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqDBM.png)

I am using APEX 19.2, anyone faced a similar issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the contents of the variable records in your situation? Can you show the content?

Comment: @Giliam I have tried different ways, one of them was to first use `let grid = apex.region("grid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews").grid.model.getRecord([1])` and set the grid with `apex.region("grid").widget().interactiveGrid("setSelectedRecords", [model]);` but it didn't worked. My record is as below: [record structure](https://imgur.com/a/6vQQGdR)

Comment: John Snyders has a detailed blog where this is covered https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/02/20/how-to-hack-apex-interactive-grid-part-3/
Look for "Widget Methods"

Comment: or another informative blog about these content is https://github.com/mgoricki/orclapex-ig-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`apex.region("gridId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").setSelectedRecords(records, true);`

Perhaps must be the record between '[]' example:

var record = apex.region("gridId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model.getRecord("4551");

apex.region("gridId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").setSelectedRecords([record],true);

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case:

```js
var val = $v("P2_SELECTED_RECEIPT");
if(!!val) {
    apex.region('receiptsGrid').widget().interactiveGrid('setSelectedRecords', [String(val)]);
}
```